# Word - Create index that displays bullet number, not page number

Tags: microsoft-word, search-indexing

I have a word doc with several hundred bullet numbers (one continuous list, let's say 1 - 300).  Every time the word "medical" appears, I want to have that paragraph number displayed in an index.  I know how to "Mark All" and automatically create an index with page numbers, but I need bullet numbers.  Is this possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Bullets don't have numbers. A bullet is an icon and indicates what is called an "Unordered List", in contrast with an "Ordered List" which has numbered points. So, are you talking about a numbered list, or bullet points? Please use the EDIT button to clarify this.